# Print out contents of a list human readable C#

Tags: c#, list

I am very new to C# and I would like to print out the contents of a list so that the information stored in seatsBooked will be displayed for the user if they pick the number 3 case of my switch statement. My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AirlineReservation

{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        bool[] seats = new bool[10];
        //To keep a separate list of seats taken          
        List<int> seatsBooked = new List<int>();
        int inputI = 0;
        char inputC = ' ';
        bool quit = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            int assignSeat = rand.Next(5, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for flying with Steve-O Airlines" + "\n" + '\n' +
                             "\nPlease enter the number one [1] for First Class" +
                             " \nPlease enter the number two [2] for Economy" +
                             "\nPlease enter the number three [3] for seats taken" +
                              "\nPlease enter the number four [4] to exit the order system");
            inputI = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (inputI)
            {
                case 1: //is the seat booked, if not book it
                    int assignedSeat;
                    if (seatsBooked.Count == 0) 
                    {
                        assignedSeat = rand.Next(0, 5);
                        seats[assignedSeat] = true;
                        seatsBooked.Add(assignedSeat);                            
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        do //while there are available seats and current seat has not being assigned before.
                        {
                            assignedSeat = rand.Next(0, 5);
                            if (!seatsBooked.Contains(assignedSeat)) //if assignedSeat is not booked.
                            {
                                seats[assignedSeat] = true;

                            }
                            //repeat while the random seat number is already booked and there are  avaialable seats
                        } while (seatsBooked.Contains(assignedSeat) && seatsBooked.Count < 5);

                        if (seatsBooked.Count < 5) //if seatsBooked list is not full for First Class
                        {
                            seatsBooked.Add(assignedSeat); //Add current random-generated seat to the list.
                        }

                    }

                    if (seatsBooked.Count >= 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("All seats for First Class are booked! Looks like a bad lunch for you.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your seat number is: {0}" + " \nNow pay me $550", assignedSeat + 1);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    seats[assignSeat] = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your seat number is: {0}"+ " \nNow pay me $350", assignSeat + 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 3:

                        Console.WriteLine(seatsBooked);  



                    break;
                case 4:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR::INVALID SELECTION" +
                        "\nYou will not get a flight this way!" );
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!quit);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have probably discovered `Console.WriteLine(seatsBooked);` will not show you the contents of the list.  One way to do that is a `foreach` loop.  The simplest form would look like this.

```
foreach(int seatBooked in seatsBooked) {
    Console.WriteLine(seatBooked);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't just print a list out like that... what ends up happening is `ToString()` is called on your collection, and you get the fully qualified name of your class instead of a list of numbers.

You can create a string, however, which will print correctly. Something like this should work:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", seatsBooked));  // concatenate elements with comma
```

If your list consists of the numbers 1 thru 5, your output would be:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: I put that in and it looks easy enough, but I still have a blinking cursor looking at me when I fill up the first class and there are numbers to display.

Comment: When I add some first class seats it keeps track of if the seats are taken or not, when I fill them up it tells me there are no more seats. Thats when I try to check the seatsBooked print out to see them

Comment: That helps thank you. I wanted to display the taken seats every time a user picks a seat